# cannot install R package in Rstudio cloud

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse

I am just starting using Rstudio Cloud in Linux and encountered issue installing the package. I just started with `tidyverse`

#install tidyverse packages

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))
options(download.file.method = "libcurl")
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

#Error I got

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘/home/skeam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R
```

I read some similar posts online and they suggested to uncheck "Use secure method for HTTP". I did that and still do not work.

Does anyone could read the error and suggested some solutions.

Kind Regards,

Synat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify CRAN Repositories:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))
```

2. Use an Alternative CRAN Repository:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"))
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

3. Check Your R Version: If your R version is outdated, some packages may not be compatible with it.